# Undefined entity error while using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a set of XML files that I need to read and format into a single CSV file. In order to read from the XML files, I have used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530857/parse-xml-file-into-python-object).

My code looks like this:

```
from os import listdir
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

files = listdir(".../blogs/")

for i in range(len(files)):
    # fname = ".../blogs/" + files[i]
    f = open(".../blogs/" + files[i], 'r')
    contents = f.read()
    tree=et.fromstring(contents)
    for el in tree.findall('post'):
        post = el.text

    f.close()
```

This gives me the error `cElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity:` at the line `tree=et.fromstring(contents)`. Oddly enough, when I run each of the commands on command line Python (without the for-loop though), it runs perfectly.

In case you want to know the XML structure, it is like this:

```
<Blog>
<date> some date </date>
<post> some blog post </post>
</Blog>
```

So what is causing this error, and how come it doesn't run from the Python file, but runs from the command line?

Update: After reading [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693515/why-is-elementtree-raising-a-parseerror) I checked `files[0]` and found that '&' symbol occurs a few times. I think that might be causing the problem. I used a random file to read when I ran the same commands on command line.

Comment: First off, should `".../blogs/"` be `"../blogs"` or `"../../blogs/"`?

Comment: Well it is certainly reading the file correctly. I don't think that is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the update, there were some symbols that I suspected might be causing a problem. 
The reason the error didn't come up when I ran the same lines on the command line is because I would randomly pick a file that didn't have any such characters.

Since I mainly required the content between the `<post>` and `</post>` tags, I created my own parser (as was suggested in [the link mentioned in the update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693515/why-is-elementtree-raising-a-parseerror)).

```
from os import listdir

files = listdir(".../blogs/")

for i in range(len(files)):

    f = open(".../blogs/" + files[i], 'r')
    contents = f.read()
    seek1 = contents.find('<post>')
    seek2 = contents.find('</post>', seek1+1)
    while(seek1!=-1):
        post = contents[seek1+5:seek2+6]
        seek1 = contents.find('<post>', seek1+1)
        seek2 = contents.find('</post>', seek1+1)

    f.close()
```