# Use BeautifulSoup to Iterate over XML to pull specific tags and store in variable

Tags: python, xml, variables, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to programming and have been trying to find a solution for this but all I can find are bits and pieces with no real luck putting it all together.

I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup4` in `python` to scrape some `xml` and store the text value in between specific tags in variables. The data is from a med student training program and right now everything needed has to be found manually. So I'm trying to increase efficiency a bit with a scraping program.

Let's say for example that I was looking at this type of test data to experiment with:

```
<AllergyList>
<Allergy>
    <Deleted>n</Deleted>
    <Status>
        <Active/>
    </Status>
    <ExternalID/>
    <Patient>
        <ExternalID/>
        <FirstName>Testcase</FirstName>
        <LastName>casetest</LastName>
    </Patient>
    <Allergen>
        <Name>Flagyl (metronidazole)</Name>
        <Drug>
           <NDCID>00025182151,00025182131,00025182150</NDCID>
        </Drug>
    </Allergen>
    <Reaction>difficulty breathing</Reaction>
    <OnsetDate>02/02/2013</OnsetDate>
 </Allergy>
<Allergy>
    <Deleted>n</Deleted>
    <Status>
        <Active/>
    </Status>
    <ExternalID/>
    <Patient>
        <ExternalID/>
        <FirstName>Testcase</FirstName>
        <LastName>casetest</LastName>
    </Patient>
    <Allergen>
        <Name>Bactrim (sulfamethoxazole-trimethoprim)</Name>
        <Drug>
            <NDCID>13310014501,49999023220</NDCID>
        </Drug>
    </Allergen>
    <Reaction>swelling</Reaction>
    <OnsetDate>05/03/2002</OnsetDate>
  </Allergy>
  <Number>2</Number>
</AllergyList>
```

I've been trying to pull the `<Name>` tag from in between multiple `<Allergen>` tags as well as the respective data from in between the `<Onsetdate>` and `<Reaction>` tags while storing the results of the pull into respective variables.

So for example I would want to pull `Flagyl (metronidazole)`, `difficulty breathing`, `02/02/2013`, then `Bactrim (sulfamethoxazole-trimethoprim)`, `swelling`, `05/03/2002`, and so on while placing them in separate variables that I can use later.

Pulling the first set from the `<Allergen>` tag is easy but I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate over the `xml` and storing the pulled data into variables. I've been trying to use a for loop while storing the data into an array or list but the way I've been writing it I always pull the same data over and over again depending on the number of iterations I calculate from the `len()` function and have since failed to store any of it into an array.

I've been racking my brain about this for a while now and I think I may just not be that smart so any help or even pointing me in the right direction would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530857/parse-xml-file-into-python-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418497/how-to-convert-xml-to-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a simple task because there isn't many nesting tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'xml')

allergies = []
for allergy in soup.find_all('Allergy'):
    d = { 
        'name': allergy.Allergen.Name.string,
        'reaction': allergy.Reaction.string,
        'on_set_date': allergy.OnsetDate.string,
    }   
    allergies.append(d)

## Use 'allergies' array of dictionaries as you want.
## Example:
print(allergies[1]['reaction'])
```

Run it with the `xml` file as argument:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile
```

And this test yields:

```
swelling
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and it did the trick. I hadn't thought of using dictionaries before. I'm a bit of a newcomer to programming and not that familiar with BeautifulSoup so this helps a lot!