# Iterate through all sub-tags and strings from an XML tag in python, without specifying sub-tag name

Tags: python, xml, parsing

My question is an add on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861489/use-beautifulsoup-to-iterate-over-xml-to-pull-specific-tags-and-store-in-variabl), but I'm not meant to use the answer section for add-on questions.

If I have part of an XML file like this:

```
  <eligibility>
    <criteria>
      <textblock>
        Inclusion Criteria:

          -  women undergoing cesarean section for any indication

          -  literate in german language

        Exclusion Criteria:

          -  history of keloids

          -  previous transversal suprapubic scars

          -  known patient hypersensitivity to any of the suture materials used in the protocol

          -  a medical disorder that could affect wound healing (eg, diabetes mellitus, chronic
             corticosteroid use)
      </textblock>
    </criteria>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <minimum_age>18 Years</minimum_age>
    <maximum_age>45 Years</maximum_age>
    <healthy_volunteers>No</healthy_volunteers>
  </eligibility>
```

I want to pull out all of the strings in this eligibility section (i.e the string in the textblock section and the gender, minimum age, maximum age and healthy volunteers sections)

using the code above I did this:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'lxml')
eligibi = []

for eligibility in soup.find_all('eligibility'):
    d = {'other_name':eligibility.criteria.textblock.string, 'gender':eligibility.gender.string}
    eligibi.append(d)

print eligibi
```

My problem is I have many files. Sometimes the structure of the XML file might be:

```
eligibility -> criteria -> textblock -> text
eligibility -> other things (e.g. gender as above) -> text
eligibility -> text
```

e.g.
if there way to just take 'take all of the sub-headings and their texts'

so in the above example, the list/dictionary would contain:
{criteria textblock: inclusion and exclusion criteria, gender: xxx, minimum_age: xxx, maximum_age: xxx, healthy_volunteers: xxx}

My problem is, in reality, I am not going to know all the specific sub-tags of the eligibility tag, as each experiment could be different (e.g. maybe some say 'pregnant women accepted', 'drug history of XXX accepted' etc)

So I just want, if I give it a tag name, it will give me all the sub-tags and text of those sub-tags in a dictionary.

Extended XML for comment:

```
<brief_title>Subcutaneous Adaption and Cosmetic Outcome Following Caesarean Delivery</brief_title>
<source>Klinikum Klagenfurt am Wörthersee</source>
```

...and then the eligibility XML section above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `lxml` installed you can try the following (this code assumes leaf elements within a given element i.e `eligibility` are unique) :

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
root = tree.getroot()

eligibi = []

for eligibility in root.xpath('//eligibility'):
    d = {}
    for e in eligibility.xpath('.//*[not(*)]'):
        d[e.tag] = e.text
    eligibi.append(d)

print eligibi
```

XPath explanation :

- **`.//*`** : find all elements within current `eligibility`, no matter its depth (`//`) and tag name (`*`)
- **`[not(*)]`** : filter elements found by the previous bit to those that don't have any child element aka leaf elements

Comment: may I ask, I apologise, I didn't realise that your code would mean that I was not able to also print elements that have only a depth of one (e.g. see edit I made at bottom of question; some of the XML file is nested as in eligibility, but others are not like brief_title, as above). Using your method, I cannot print the brief_title or source, because I am filtering out the child element. Would you recommend, in this situation, that I somehow run this function twice, once as above, and then once where I remove the filter for child nodes so I also get the tags that have only a depth of one? Thank

Comment: Try to change the xpath to include current context element (self): `descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]`

Comment: I've discovered I'm missing some parsed data because some of the tags looks like this: `<enrollment type="Actual">60</enrollment>` ; where the tag has an attribute, I would like to pull out the word 60 (and 'actual' if possible, but maybe that's too hard). I can post the full code and XML file here if helpful. I think the general idea is I need to edit the above snippet of code to see if the tag (e.g. here enrollment) has an attribute (like this enrollment.attrib[any attribute] and then print the tag, attribute and value? I want to check if this is the right idea as I can't get it to work?

Comment: Attribute in `lxml` element model is just a dictionary so you can get attribute value from a given element like : `my_element.attrib["attribute_name"]`. Anyway, you should post a new question for that, make sure to include representative XML sample and your attempted code