# How to remove XML tags using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, xml

A string in python can contain certain plain text as well as few XML tags containing certain information. For example:

```
The student XYZ abc has been terminated from the institute. 
you can find the details of student below:
<info StatusCode="End">
    <user_detail>
        <name>
            <first_name>ABC</first_name>
            <last_name>XYZ</last_name>
        </name>
        <contact_details>
            <contact_number>
                <number_type>landline</number_type>
                <number>1234567</number>
            </contact_number>
            <address>
                <address_field1> lorem ipsum, qwerty </address_field1>
                <address_field2> lorem ipsum2, qwerty2 </address_field2>
                <city> asdfgh </city>
                <state> zxcvbn </state>
                <country> India </country>
            </address>
        </contact_details>
    </user_detail>
    <flight_detail>
        ...
    </flight_detail>
</info>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro ea dicat velit regione, modo putant 
sensibus pri id, ut bonorum scripserit sit. Ex nec tation alienum, est ut 
nemore efficiendi interpretaris, vis te reque eleifend. 
<xml_tag>
...
</xml_tag>
Laudem delectus
reprehendunt ei mei, has nisl dolorem mnesarchum no, ad eos modo singulis
euripidis. Quo no consul offendit. Eu alia utroque argumentum vix, no 
case primis eum.
<xml_tag>
....
</xml_tag>
```

It is not fixed that the opening tag of XML will be `<info>`, it can be anything like `<session StatusCode="End">` and in this case, ending tag will be `</session>`.
Currently, I am removing this xml tags using

```
data = re.sub(r'<[^<]+>', "", data)
```

But, now I want to remove all XML content from this text.The final output that I want now is:

```
The student XYZ abc has been terminated from the institute. 
you can find the details of student below:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro ea dicat velit regione, modo putant 
sensibus pri id, ut bonorum scripserit sit. Ex nec tation alienum, est ut 
nemore efficiendi interpretaris, vis te reque eleifend. 
Laudem delectus
reprehendunt ei mei, has nisl dolorem mnesarchum no, ad eos modo singulis
euripidis. Quo no consul offendit. Eu alia utroque argumentum vix, no 
case primis eum.
```

I tried matching using `</\S+>`, but it will remove till first closing XML tag. How can I remove all the XML content from plain text string that can contain simple text also.

Comment: I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560748/iterate-through-all-sub-tags-and-strings-from-an-xml-tag-in-python-without-spec) that helped me.

Comment: "But, " does not actually state the problem or the result you get. What exactly does you code not do? Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<(.*?>)(.*)</\1` with single line option, matches the XML you wish to remove. The innerxml is in the second group

See https://regex101.com/r/HwiA2t/1

Comment: How to configure regex to single line option in python? Isn't it by default set to single line option?

Comment: use DOTALL or s modifier http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall  
eg `re.compile(r'_(regex)_', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: It does not work if their is some property listed in tag, for example: <info class="sample"> https://regex101.com/r/HwiA2t/2

Comment: To accommodate attributes, use `<(?:(.*?)\s.+?>)(.*?)</\1[>]?`     See https://regex101.com/r/HwiA2t/3

Comment: regex101.com/r/HwiA2t/3 In this example given by you, the data out of XML tags is also getting removed in the last part.

Comment: Updated `<(?:(.*?)(\s.+)?>)(.*?)</\1[>]?`     See https://regex101.com/r/HwiA2t/4