# parsing XML file gets UnicodeEncodeError (ElementTree) / ValueError (lxml)

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, lxml, elementtree

I send a GET request to the [CareerBuilder API](http://api.careerbuilder.com/) :

```
import requests

url = "http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch"
payload = {'DeveloperKey': 'MY_DEVLOPER_KEY',
           'JobTitle': 'Biologist'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
xml = r.text
```

And get back an XML that looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/jwXdYhMf). However, I have trouble parsing it.

Using either `lxml`

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> print etree.fromstring(xml)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    print etree.fromstring(xml)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2992, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:62311)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1585, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91625)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.
```

or `ElementTree:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print ET.fromstring(xml)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1301, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1641, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3717: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, even though the XML file starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I have the impression that it contains characters that are not allowed. How do I parse this file with either `lxml`or `ElementTree`?

Comment: Related: [How can I convert XML into a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/418497/3357935)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using the *decoded* unicode value. Use [`r.raw` raw response data](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) instead:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=payload, stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
etree.parse(r.raw)
```

which will read the data from the response directly; do note the `stream=True` option to `.get()`.

Setting the `r.raw.decode_content = True` flag ensures that the raw socket will give you the decompressed content even if the response is gzip or deflate compressed.

You don't *have* to stream the response; for smaller XML documents it is fine to use the [`response.content` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content), which is the un-decoded response body:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
xml = etree.fromstring(r.content)
```

XML parsers always expect bytes as input as the XML format itself dictates how the parser is to decode those bytes to Unicode text.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `etree.parse(r.raw)` over `etree.fromstring(r.content)`?

Answer (score 5):

### Correction!

See below how I got it all wrong. Basically, when we use the method `.text` then the result is a unicode encoded string. Using it raises the following exception in lxml

> ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not
>   supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without
>   declaration.

Which basically means that @martijn-pieters was right, we must use the raw response as returned by `.content`

#### Incorrect answer (but might be interesting to someone)

For whoever is interested. I believe the reason this error occurs is probably an invalid guess taken by requests as explained in [`Response.text` documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text):

> Content of the response, in unicode.
>
> If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using chardet.
>
> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on
>   HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take
>   advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the
>   encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing
>   this property.

So, following this, one could also make sure requests' `r.text` encodes the response content correctly by explicitly setting the encoding with `r.encoding = 'UTF-8'`

This approach adds another validation that the received response is indeed in the correct encoding prior to parsing it with lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the question has already got its answer, I faced this similar issue on Python3 and it worked fine on Python2. My resolution was: `str_xml.encode()` and then `xml = etree.fromstring(str_xml)` and then the parsing and extractions of tags and attributes.