# XML Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported

Tags: python, xml, django

Trying to do the following...

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import fromstring

if request.POST:
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
    h = fromstring(request.POST['xml'], parser=parser)
    return HttpResponse(h.cssselect('itagg_delivery_receipt status').text_content())
```

but it give this error:

```
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error] Internal Server Error: /sms/status_postback/
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]   File "/srv/project/livewireSMS/sms/views.py", line 42, in update_delivery_status
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]     h = fromstring(request.POST['xml'], parser=parser)
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]   File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2754, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54631)
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error]   File "parser.pxi", line 1569, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82659)
[Fri Apr 05 10:27:54 2013] [error] ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.
```

this is the XML

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<itagg_delivery_receipt>
<version>1.0</version>
<msisdn>447889000000</msisdn>
<submission_ref>
845tgrgsehg394g3hdfhhh56445y7ts6</
submission_ref>
<status>Delivered</status>
<reason>4</reason>
<timestamp>20050709120945</timestamp>
<retry>0</retry>
</itagg_delivery_receipt>
```

I don't have control over the xml document this comes from the SMS company.

Comment: From the lxml FAQ: [*Why can't lxml parse my XML from unicode strings?*](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-can-t-lxml-parse-my-xml-from-unicode-strings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing XML file gets UnicodeEncodeError (ElementTree) / ValueError (lxml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622027/parsing-xml-file-gets-unicodeencodeerror-elementtree-valueerror-lxml)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You'll have to encode it and then force the same encoding in the parser:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import fromstring

if request.POST:
    xml = request.POST['xml'].encode('utf-8')
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True, encoding='utf-8')
    h = fromstring(xml, parser=parser)

    return HttpResponse(h.cssselect('delivery_reciept status').text_content())
```

Comment: Can a standalone example be provided where the XML data is defined in the code?

Comment: this solution doesn't help with encoding problems.

Answer (score 23):

The following solution from [kernc](https://gist.github.com/karlcow/3258330#gistcomment-769151) worked for me:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><foo><bar/></foo>'
xml = bytes(bytearray(xml, encoding='utf-8'))  # ADDENDUM OF THIS LINE (when unicode means utf-8, e.g. on Linux)
etree.XML(xml)

# <Element html at 0x5b44c90>
```

Comment: Interesting. Even after reading the [page](https://gist.github.com/karlcow/3258330#gistcomment-769151) suggesting the workaround, I sill miss why decoding fails... :S

Answer (score 20):

More simple than answers above:

```py
from lxml import etree

#Do request for data, response = r#
data = etree.fromstring(bytes(r.text, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Apologies all as at this time I was young, dumb and not quite mature enough to take the effort to explain my answer (nor did I have the knowledge really)

- `fromstring()` is a custom constructor for the `etree` object as part of the `lxml` library
- XML in the form of a string may contain characters which are not encoded how this constructor would like them to be -> thus you can encode them into `utf-8` bytes and this will align with the `fromstring()` constructor requirements

Comment: You might add some explanations to your solution, so that later users can follow your code more easily.

Comment: What type is r ?

Comment: The variable r would be from the request library. So you would have  r = requests.get(URL).