# parse xml document (on url) in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I am trying to parse xml document (URL) using requests,

facing following error:

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported
```

here is my code:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import fromstring

req = requests.request('GET', "http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastC.xml")

a = req.text
b = etree.fromstring(a)
```

how can i get this xml parsed. Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830421/xml-unicode-strings-with-encoding-declaration-are-not-supported

Comment: @AlexeyGorozhanov i tried it.. not working for me! throws same error

Comment: @quikrr: it cannot possibly throw the same error if you actually used `req.content`; are you 100% certain you used the right method there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in the *Unicode decoded version*. Don't do that, XML parsers require that you pass in the raw bytes instead.

Instead of `req.text`, use `req.content` here:

```
a = req.content
b = etree.fromstring(a)
```

You can also *stream* the XML document to the parser:

```
req = requests.get("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastC.xml", stream=True)
req.raw.decode_content = True  # ensure transfer encoding is honoured
b = etree.parse(req.raw)
```