# lxml can not parse xml (wether encoding is utf-8 or not) [python]

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

My code:

```
import re
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://weixin.sogou.com/gzhjs?openid=oIWsFt__d2wSBKMfQtkFfeVq_u8I&ext=2JjmXOu9jMsFW8Sh4E_XmC0DOkcPpGX18Zm8qPG7F0L5ffrupfFtkDqSOm47Bv9U'

r = requests.get(url)

items = r.json()['items']
```

1. without encode('utf-8'):

`etree.fromstring(items[0])`   output:

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-cb8697498318> in <module>()
----> 1 etree.fromstring(items[0])

lxml.etree.pyx in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:68121)()

parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102435)()

ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

2. with encode('utf-8'):

`etree.fromstring(items[0].encode('utf-8'))` output:

```
  File "<string>", line unknown
XMLSyntaxError: CData section not finished
鎶楀啺鎶㈤櫓鎹锋姤:闃冲寳I绾挎, line 1, column 281
```

Have not idea to parse this xml..

Comment: Look at the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830421/xml-unicode-strings-with-encoding-declaration-are-not-supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, you can remove `encoding` attribute before pass the string to `etree.fromstring`:

```
xml = re.sub(r'\bencoding="[-\w]+"', '', items[0], count=1)
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

**UPDATE** after seeing @Lea's comment in the question:

Specify parser with explicit encoding:

```
xml = r.json()['items'].encode('utf-8')
root = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: Could you mind to give me a explanation about why etree fail?if I get `XMLSyntaxError`, remove `encoding` would always work?

Comment: @Mithril, I **guess** that mismatch between `gbk` and `utf-8` cause parser to interpret tag as non-tag.

Comment: Seems there is not a all-powerful way to solve all such kind errors. Thank you very much.

Comment: I wanted to see if instead of removing the encoding from the xml if lxml could use the gbk encoding.  got the following:
    blah = etree.fromstring(items[0].encode('gbk'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\ue468' in position 82: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: @Marcel Wilson  I think `r.json()` decode the response to `utf-8`, so `encode('gbk')` not work.