# xml.etree.ElementTree findall

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML [file](https://s137-en.ogame.gameforge.com/api/players.xml) using **xml.etree.ElementTree**. I want to find elements based off the name attribute.

```
fnd = root.findall("./player[@name='Pqp239']")
```

But, this only will find exact matches for the name. How would you go about finding elements whose name contains a part of a name? So it would be something like this

```
fnd = root.findall("./player[@name='rob']")
```

would find all elemnts whose name contain rob like these:

```
Rob
Robert
chifforobe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`contains()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064968/how-to-use-xpath-contains-here), but this would only work if you would switch to [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree` which has only *partial/limited XPath support*:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

root.xpath("./player[contains(@name, 'rob')]")
```

Note though, that to make the partial match case-insensitive you would need to additionally apply the [`translate()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate):

- [case insensitive xpath contains() possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)

Comment: With translate(), instead of typing the whole alphabet, would be possible to use [a-z] and [A-Z]?

Comment: @Pqp239 nope, but it's not that the english alphabet changes frequently :)

Comment: I thought I was missing out on some new findall capabilities ;)

Comment: I installed lxml just now and am getting `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.` How would I fix this issue? This happens when I parse it.

Comment: @Pqp239 okay, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830421/xml-unicode-strings-with-encoding-declaration-are-not-supported.