# Python 3 lxml.Objectify

Tags: python, lxml

I have a small script that makes requests with `httplib2` which returns the response body as bytes. I normally want to immediately decode it to str so that my code can work as it previously did with 2.7.

However, when the response is XML with encoding as the first line, `lxml.objectify` fails in python 3 as it expects bytes not str. What is the best way to go from XML str to a objectified object in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

To parse `xml` from a string using `lxml`, you can use `.fromstring()` method.

Example:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = '<a xmlns="test"><b xmlns="test"/></a>'

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer that doesn't work. I had a check (which I should have done first and it looks like it's not a clean solution). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830421/xml-unicode-strings-with-encoding-declaration-are-not-supported

Comment: @user7692855, could you update the question to incldue the code you've tried/response you get/any errors? so it's minimal reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example