# Error with Python and XML

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, lxml

I'm getting an error when trying to grab a value from my XML. I get "Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration."

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r= requests.get("https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
print r.text

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.text)
textelem = root.find("opensearch:totalResults")
print textelem.text
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tickets2.py", line 8, in <module>
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.text)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82934)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1814, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124471)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

Here is what the XML looks like, where I'm trying to grab the file in the last line.

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:apple-wallpapers="http://www.apple.com/ilife/wallpapers" xmlns:g-custom="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:g-core="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <title>Feed from some link here</title>
  <link rel="self" href="https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc" />
  <link rel="first" href="https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc" />
  <id>https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc</id>
  <updated>2018-03-06T17:48:09Z</updated>
  <dc:creator>company.com</dc:creator>
  <dc:date>2018-03-06T17:48:09Z</dc:date>
  <opensearch:totalResults>4</opensearch:totalResults>
```

I have tried various changes from links like https://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/06/python-lxml-strings-with-encoding.html and http://makble.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-python-and-lxml but I keep running into the same error.

Comment: Maybe try `lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `r.text`, which guesses at the text encoding and decodes it, try using `r.content` which accesses the response body as bytes. (See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content.)

You could also use `r.raw`. See [parsing XML file gets UnicodeEncodeError (ElementTree) / ValueError (lxml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622027/parsing-xml-file-gets-unicodeencodeerror-elementtree-valueerror-lxml) for more info.

Once that issue is fixed, you'll have the issue of the namespace. The element you're trying to find (`opensearch:totalResults`) has the prefix `opensearch` which is bound to the uri `http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/`.

You can find the element by combining the namespace uri and the local name (Clark notation):

```
{http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/}totalResults
```

See http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces for more info.

Here's an example with both changes implemented:

```
os = "{http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/}"

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)
textelem = root.find(os + "totalResults")
print textelem.text
```

Comment: That was awesome. That last part you sent worked like a charm. Thank you very much.