# Can I automatically convert an XML file into a Python object?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.7

I am asking this question because I know that [C# has such facilities](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/serialize-and-deserialize-xml-file-into-c-sharp-object-and-vise-versa) in the .net framework.

Suppose, I have an XML file as follows:

**`data.xml`**

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">item1abc</item>
        <item name="item2">item2abc</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

And, the following is a Python class `Data` that is modeled after `data.xml`:

**`Data.py`**

```
class Attribue:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.__name = name
        self.__value = value

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

class Item:
    def __init__(self, attr, value):
        self.__attr = attr
        self.__value = value

    def get_attr(self):
        return self.__attr

    def set_attr(self, attr):
        self.__attr = attr

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value


class Data:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.__items = items;

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__items 

    def set_value(self, items):
        self.__items = items

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.__items.adppend(item);

    def return_item(self, item):
        self.__items.get(item)
```

Is there any module or package in Python which can automatically load that XML file into an instance of the class **`Data`**?

For example, the sample code can be as follows:

```
data = Data()

data = xml.load(type(Data), "data.xml")

print(data.items[0].attr.name)
print(data.items[0].attr.value)
print(data.items[0].value)
```

The sample output can be as follows:

```
name
item1
item1abc
```

---

Disclaimer: this is not homework.

Comment: Does Python need such a thing instead of dictionary?

Comment: "Can I automatically convert an XML file into a Python object?". I think the general answer is yes. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/418497/407651, https://code.activestate.com/recipes/534109-xml-to-python-data-structure/. But note that asking for recommendations of tools or libraries is off-topic.