# How can I read 3 kinds of XML files using only one function?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

Suppose, I have the following 3 kinds of XML files:

**`file1.xml`**

```
<memberdef>
    <param>
        <type>abc12300xyz__param -> type</type>
    </param>
</memberdef>
```

**`file2.xml`**

```
<memberdef>
    <param>
        <type>abc12300xyz__param -> type</type>
        <declname>abc12300xyz__param -> declname</declname>
    </param>
</memberdef>
```

**`file3.xml`**

```
<memberdef>
    <param>
        <type>
            <ref refid="abc12300xyz__refid" kindref="abc12300xyz__kindref">abc12300xyz -> ref</ref>
        </type>
        <declname>abc12300xyz__param -> declname</declname>
    </param>
</memberdef>
```

Suppose, I want to read these three files using [LXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419232/159072).

How do I know/test which file is loaded?

For instance, when either **`file1.xml`** or **`file2.xml`** are loaded, the following source code fails:

```
if memberdef.param.type.ref != None:
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
```

What tactic should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple XPath check for element existance (replace `fileX.xml`). The XPath expressions do only return a non-empty result if the elements are present in the given XML file. In the below example, the test goes down from very specific to more general:

```
from lxml import etree

print("Checking variants...")
root = etree.parse("fileX.xml")
if root.xpath('/memberdef[param[type/ref and declname]]'):
    print("Third variant.")
elif root.xpath('/memberdef[param[type and declname]]'):
    print("Second variant.")
elif root.xpath('/memberdef/param[type]'):
    print("First variant.")
else:
    print("None of the given variants.")
```

So

- the first IF checks if the `memberdef` element has a `param` child that has a `type/ref` child and a `declname` child.
- the second IF only checks if the `memberdef` element has a `param` child that has a `type` child and a `declname` child.
- the third IF checks if the `memberdef` element has a `param` child that has a `type` child.

And so on, you should get the gist.