# How to convert XML to JSON in Python

Tags: python, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting XML to JSON using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python)

I am importing an XML feed and trying to convert it to JSON for output. I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: <xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x72787d8> is not JSON serializable`

Unfortunately I know next to nothing about Python. I'm developing this on the Google App Engine. I could use some help, because my little 2 hour hack that was going so well is now on its 3rd day.

XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2009-01-25 15:03:27</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID" key="characterID" name="characters">
      <row characterID="999999" corporationID="999999" corporationName="filler data" name="someName"/>
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2009-01-25 15:04:55</cachedUntil>

</eveapi>
```

My code:

```
class doproxy(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    apiurl = 'http://api.eve-online.com'

    path = self.request.get('path');
    type = self.request.get('type');
    args = '&'+self.request.get('args');

    #assemble api url
    url = apiurl+path

    #do GET request     
    if type == 'get':
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url,'','get');

    #do POST request
    if type == 'post':
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url,args,'post');   

    if result.status_code == 200:               
        dom = minidom.parseString( result.content ) #.encode( "utf-8" ) )
        dom2json = simplejson.dump(dom,"utf-8")
```

Comment: Why was this down voted?  Yeah the OP is definitely new to Python and coding but the fastest way to learn is to ask questions like this.

Comment: I believe the way the question is written caused the downvoting.

Comment: probably down voted because he said python is not documented...

Comment: Question isn't well written but it's a decent one.  I've edited.  Let's remove some downvotes -this is probably useful to other people.

Comment: Why do you ask about the same (identical title) thing you asked 2 days ago at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471946/ ?

Comment: Piotr, this question is over 3 years old. I asked it when I was new to Python. I was also relatively new to the site at the time too. If you look at my profile, I've progressed quite a bit since then. =) In retrospect, this question was appropriately closed at the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm quickly coming to the opinion that
>   Python is potentially a great
>   language, but that none of its users
>   know how to actually document anything
>   in a clear and concise way.

The attitude of the question isn't going to help with getting answers from these same Python users.

As is mentioned in the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python), there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between XML and JSON so the conversion can't be done automatically.

In [the documentation for `simplejson`](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.7/docs/index.html) you can find the list of types that it's able to serialize, which are basically the native Python types (dict, list, unicode, int, float, True/False, None).

So, you have to create a Python data structure containing only these types, which you will then give to `simplejson.dump()`.

Comment: @Geuis I recommend you pick up an introduction to Computer science book, your going to be banging your head against a wall until you start getting the big picture of data structures and software design.