# Where to start with parsing JSON?

Tags: python, json, facebook

If I have JSON data stored in a string called 'data' (e.g. the example below) how do I access specific information (such as `messages->unread` or `pokes->most_recent`)?

```
{
  "messages": {
    "unread": 0,
    "most_recent": 1300047276
  },
  "pokes": {
    "unread": 0,
    "most_recent": 0
  },
  "shares": {
    "unread": 0,
    "most_recent": 0
  },
  "friend_requests": [],
  "group_invites": [],
  "event_invites": []
}
```

I'd like something like `data['messages']['unread']` to work - but of course it won't when my data is stored as a string!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON parser is bundled with Python since 2.6: [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. To unserialize a string, use `json.loads`, e.g.

```
import json
data = json.loads(...)
```

You can also load directly from a file-like object with `json.load`.

Comment: Is there a difference between json and simplejson?

Comment: @fluteflute: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You run the string through a JSON parser to turn it into a suitable data structure for whatever language you are using (sets, arrays, strings, etc in Python) . There are a number listed near the bottom of http://json.org/ for a variety of languages.