# python: library behavior on failed import

Tags: python, import, importerror

Is there any standard practice on how a library should behave, when certain module can't be imported? Should it just let an exception fly or should it rather catch it and exit elegantly with a proper information?

For example I have something like this:

```
try:
   from argparse import ArgumentParser
except ImportError:
   print('fathom library requires python 3.2 or argparse package.')
```

Is it better or worse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library should always raise an `ImportError` instead of exiting; the program may want to conditionally include it (perhaps replacing it when it is not available).

If a lower-level module raises `ImportError`, your best shot is to re-raise it with extra information attached.

Comment: Your first paragraph is confusing. In each of 2 cases (A attempts to import B, and A attempts to import B which attempts to import C), please say which is "a library", "the program" and "it". The most plausible interpretation is A==program, B==library, C==it ... but "it" has no referent.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, distribute the module with your package, and then follow this pattern to choose which one you're using (prefer the Python 3.x one, default to your shipped one).

If not, this is generally okay as long as you also make sure this doesn't silently cause a more obscure exception later on (ie, make sure you cleanup at the end of the `except` and in all likelihood, either re-throw this exception or throw your own).

PS - [This wasn't an uncommon occurrence for `simplejson` before it got included in Python proper as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python/712799#712799)

Comment: This is a neat idea. I will include `argparse` package to my library as a fallback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of taste. I like your method though. It's clear and clean.