# What's the main difference between simplejson and the module in the standard library of python?

Tags: python, json, simplejson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`json` and `simplejson` module differences in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python)

On [this page about json](http://www.JSON.org/json-de.html), I read about json and the python modules available for json. The mention those four libraries:

- Json in the Python Standard Library.
- simplejson.
- pyson.
- Yajl-Py

Which one is recommended? What is the main difference between the library from the standard library and simplejson?

Comment: @GaretJax: I didn't notice the question was already there. Thanks!

Comment: It was the first search result in google for "simplejson vs json"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json in the standard library *is* simplejson, only bit older version, maintained more slowly. As for which to use, stdlib json unless you have a good reason not to.