# How to print particular JSON value in Python?

Tags: python, json

So I have a Python code which returns a JSON string like this one:

```
'{"X": "value1", "Y": "value2", "Z": [{"A": "value3", "B": "value4"}]}'
```

What I want to do is to print and/or return (in Python) `"value 3"` in order to use it. Also assign it to a variable so I can work with it later on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake on the code!! thnx!

Comment: NOTE: I'm using the "simplejson" module to parse the data

Comment: Your input still is no valid JSON. `value1` and `value4` must be inside quotes. Even `simplejson` can't decode your input.

Comment: Please post some of the code you are trying so we don't have to guess which module you use.

Comment: Btw, simplejson is same as the json library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python

Comment: But make sure you really need a list here: "Z":[{"A":"value3","B":"value4"}]. Maybe "Z":{"A":"value3","B":"value4"} will be enough, then you could get to value3 like this: a["Z"]["A"], instead of a["Z"][0]["A"].

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> a = json.loads('{"X":"value1","Y":"value2","Z":[{"A":"value3","B":"value4"}]}')
>>> a
{'Y': 'value2', 'X': 'value1', 'Z': [{'A': 'value3', 'B': 'value4'}]}
>>> a["Z"][0]["A"]
'value3'
```

Comment: Oh! two Things: I'm using "simplejson" module to parse the data, and my string is like the recently edited one in my question... Does your answer applies? because I'm using simplejson.loads(datavariable)

Comment: Thanks! This worked flawlessly for what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: Any tutorial I can read in order to get more familiar with reading certain values from JSON strings in Python?

Comment: Well, where was the problem? Was it loading the JSON string into a Python object, or was it finding the correct way to access elements?

Comment: The correct way to access the elements... I know how to parse json data in python and assign a variable for that "task" but what I wasn't sure is about to "pick" special values from that data and assign them a variable too... Any suggestions on reading material? :)

Comment: That's very basic Python knowledge - I'd suggest the excellent [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) on the official website (you should read it entirely anyway, but [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are the most relevant sections for this).

Answer (score 5):

OK, I assume your JSON looks like this (note the `"` around each `value`):

```
{"X":"value1", "Y":"value2", "Z":[{"A":"value3", "B":"value4"}]}
```

Then you can do this:

```
import json
j = '{"X":"value1", "Y":"value2", "Z":[{"A":"value3", "B":"value4"}]}'
k = json.loads(j)
assert k["Z"][0]["A"] == "value3"
```

**Edit:** Even `simplejson`can't decode your original input.

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> s1 = '{"X":value1,"Y":"value2","Z":[{"A":"value3","B":value4}]}'
>>> simplejson.loads(s1)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
>>> s2 = '{"X":"value1", "Y":"value2", "Z":[{"A":"value3", "B":"value4"}]}'
>>> print simplejson.loads(s2)["Z"][0]["A"]
value3
```

Comment: Oh! two Things: I'm using "simplejson" module to parse the data, and my string is like the recently edited one in my question... Does your answer applies? because I'm using  simplejson.loads(datavariable)