# How to sort certain json objects in python

Tags: python, json, api, sorting

```
import requests
import random
import json

#uses api to get a random pokemon
pokeid = str(random.randrange(0, 807))
url = ('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
fullurl = (url+pokeid)

#json stuff
pokemon = requests.get(fullurl)
jspoke = pokemon.json()

print(jspoke)
```

this grabs a pokemon info json string from an api and it prints

```
{'abilities': [{'ability': {'name': 'battle-armor', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/4/'}, 'is_hidden': False, 'slot': 1}], 'base_experience': 107, 'forms': [{'name': 'type-null', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/772/'}], 'game_indices': [], 'height': 19, 'held_items': [], 'id': 772, 'is_default': True, 'location_area_encounters': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/772/encounters', 'moves': [{'move': {'name': 'razor-wind', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/13/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 70, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 70, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'swords-dance', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/14/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'tackle', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/33/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 1, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 1, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'take-down', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/36/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 40, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 40, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'double-edge', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/38/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 80, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 80, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'roar', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/46/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'thunder-wave', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/86/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'toxic', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/92/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'rage', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/99/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 5, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 5, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'double-team', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/104/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'rest', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/156/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'rock-slide', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/157/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'tri-attack', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/161/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 75, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 75, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'substitute', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/164/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'protect', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/182/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'scary-face', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/184/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 30, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 30, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'sandstorm', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/201/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'swagger', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/207/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'sleep-talk', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/214/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'return', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/216/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'frustration', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/218/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'pursuit', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/228/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 10, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 10, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'hidden-power', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/237/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'rain-dance', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/240/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'sunny-day', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/241/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'hail', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/258/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'facade', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/263/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'imprison', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/286/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 15, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 15, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'crush-claw', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/306/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 25, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 25, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'metal-sound', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/319/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 45, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 45, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'aerial-ace', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/332/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 20, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 20, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'dragon-claw', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/337/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'u-turn', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/369/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'payback', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/371/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'heal-block', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/377/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 85, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 85, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'punishment', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/386/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 65, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 65, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'air-slash', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/403/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 60, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 60, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'x-scissor', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/404/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 35, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 35, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'giga-impact', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/416/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'shadow-claw', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/421/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'iron-head', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/442/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 50, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 50, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'double-hit', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/458/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 55, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 55, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'level-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'flame-charge', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/488/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'round', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/496/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'work-up', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/526/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}, {'move': {'name': 'confide', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/590/'}, 'version_group_details': [{'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'sun-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/'}}, {'level_learned_at': 0, 'move_learn_method': {'name': 'machine', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/4/'}, 'version_group': {'name': 'ultra-sun-ultra-moon', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/'}}]}], 'name': 'type-null', 'order': 907, 'species': {'name': 'type-null', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/772/'}, 'sprites': {'back_default': None, 'back_female': None, 'back_shiny': None, 'back_shiny_female': None, 'front_default': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/772.png', 'front_female': None, 'front_shiny': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/772.png', 'front_shiny_female': None}, 'stats': [{'base_stat': 95, 'effort': 2, 'stat': {'name': 'hp', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/'}}, {'base_stat': 95, 'effort': 0, 'stat': {'name': 'attack', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/'}}, {'base_stat': 95, 'effort': 0, 'stat': {'name': 'defense', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/3/'}}, {'base_stat': 95, 'effort': 0, 'stat': {'name': 'special-attack', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/'}}, {'base_stat': 95, 'effort': 0, 'stat': {'name': 'special-defense', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/'}}, {'base_stat': 59, 'effort': 0, 'stat': {'name': 'speed', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/'}}], 'types': [{'slot': 1, 'type': {'name': 'normal', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/1/'}}], 'weight': 1205}
```

how do I make it so it only prints The url in species?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093684/how-to-print-particular-json-value-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jspoke` in your case is a dictionary.  Dictionaries in python have keys and values.  species is a key of `jspoke` (which is another dictionary).  To print the `url` value of the `species` value of `jspoke` you should write:

```py
print(jspoke['species']['url'])
```

[Read more about dictionaries in Pythons documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)