# Any reason to continue using simplejson over the included json in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

The reason in the past used to be that simplejson was way faster than the included json but now they are pretty similar in speed. Do I get any benefits sticking with simplejson anymore or should I switch all my code over to the included json now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [`json` and `simplejson` module differences in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

One practical difference is that when loading JSON strings, the json module will always return a Python unicode object, but simplejson will return a str (byte string) unless the JSON string contains Unicode code points:

```
>>> json.loads('"test"')
u'test'
>>> simplejson.loads('"test"')
'test'
>>> simplejson.loads('"\\u1000"')
u'\u1000'
```

So, you may want to stick with simplejson if you have poorly written code that can't handle unicode returns when loading JSON (I say poorly written because `simplejson.loads()` will return unicode depending on the JSON string).

Answer (score -1):

Google appengine doesn't support json. On top of that simplejson is more updated than json