# Convert Python None to JavaScript null

Tags: javascript, python, django

In a Django view I am generating a data set something like this:

```
data = [22, 23, 18, 19, 21, None, 22, 20]
```

I am passing this data to a JavaScript variable using:

```
data_json = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

For use in a High Charts script.

Unfortunately JavaScript is stumbling when it encounters the `None` value because actually what I need is `null`. How can I best replace `None` with `null`, and where should I handle this - in the Django View or in the JavaScript?

Comment: What version are you using of simplejson? According to the documentation, None should be converted to null automatically (see http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.6 or later, you can use the built-in json module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([1, 2, 3, None, 4])
'[1, 2, 3, null, 4]'
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: And even an updated version of simplejson would work as well.

Comment: That worked. Not sure why simplejson didn't do it. Any disadvantage in using json as opposed to simplejson in Django?

Comment: Ok - now simplejson seems to work to... Not sure whant was happeing but I was definitely getting None in my json dump yesterday

Comment: I've never run any benchmarks comparing them myself but at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python people are saying simplejson is faster. (And of course, if you need compatibility with Python 2.5 the built-in json module is out.)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the accepted solution `json.dumps()` returned NaN values rather than the null JavaScript is looking for. Therefore I found another solution that does not use json or simplejson packages. The following solution uses type checking of None in Django. The solution that inspired me can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665771/check-for-none-in-an-array-in-flask-jinja-template).

I used it in my code as follows to populate a Javascript array correctly:

```
[
{% for val in data %}
     {% if val is none %}
         null,
     {% else %}
         {{ val }},
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
],
```

The none object in Django will check the None value offered by python. It doesn't seem to correctly handle np.NaN objects though.