# How to write a JS null to file in Python instead of 'null' as a string

Tags: javascript, python, null

My problem is that I need to write a `null` object to a file, for use in JavaScript.

When I write 'null' JavaScript understands it as a string.

For example in Python:

```
null_list = ['null']*10
# output: ['null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null']
```

While in JavaScript I need :

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: can you specify your requirement more

Comment: Your question is *horrifyingly* unclear.  What do you want the file to contain? How are you writing it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print the list without the `"` around `null`?

Comment: Sorry for the confused statement above, thanks all you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the built-in module `json` to convert Python's `None` to the JS `null`.

```
>>> import json
>>> null_list = [None]*10
>>> null_list
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> json.dumps(null_list)
'[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]'
```

(As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947311/2359271) to a similar question.)