# check for None in an array in flask (jinja template)

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a weird situation where array has value as None:

`'synonyms': [None]`

The json format of data in mongo is as:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0983a63bcf0dab51f32a9d"
    },
    "word": "vulgarizer",
    "wordset_id": "c0c349060a",
    "labels": [{
        "name": "American",
        "is_dialect": true
    }],
    "meanings": [{
        "id": "3cb39b55e5",
        "def": "someone who makes attractive to the general public",
        "speech_part": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["populariser"]
    }, {
        "id": "865bfdea0b",
        "def": "someone who makes something vulgar",
        "speech_part": "noun",
        "synonyms": [null]
    }],
    "editors": ["lefurjah"],
    "contributors": ["luxfactaest", "msingle", "bryanedu"]
}
```

But when I tried printing the same in python it showed up as:

```
'meanings': [{
    'id': '3cb39b55e5',
    'def': 'someone who makes attractive to the general public',
    'speech_part': 'noun',
    'synonyms': ['populariser']
}, {
    'id': '865bfdea0b',
    'def': 'someone who makes something vulgar',
    'speech_part': 'noun',
    'synonyms': [None]
}]
```

How do I check this value in `if` condition :

I have tried as:

```
{% if meaning['synonyms'] is defined and meaning['synonyms']|length > 0 %}
    do something-- if condition matches
```

But the None in array doesn't refer to a null value ?

Any possible solution? TIA

Comment: ideally if there are no synonyms then list should be empty instead of `[None]`

Comment: I have updated the code in Q , please look at the data in db

Comment: @Codenewbie what should be when `synonyms` has more that 1 element(`[None, 'Codenewbie']`)?

Comment: I then tried if it is 'string' then do something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` condition inside `jinja` (as in *Python*).

```
from jinja2 import Template

data = {"synonyms": [None], "synonyms2": ['ok']}
tm = Template(
    "None in synonyms: {{ None in data['synonyms'] }}\n"
    "None in synonyms2: {{ None in data['synonyms2'] }}\n"
    "{% if None in data['synonyms'] %}None in synonyms {% endif %}\n"
    "{% if None in data['synonyms2'] %}None in synonyms2 {% endif %}\n"
)
msg = tm.render(data=data)
print(msg)
```

Result:

```
None in synonyms: True
None in synonyms2: False
None in synonyms
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah , this helps I guess , thanks for the example sir

Comment: I tried this a perfect solution, for other's reference here is the exact solution for my Q digged out from @Danila Ganchar ------{% if not None in meaning['synonyms']  %}