# How can I replace simplejson with json in django python?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my views:

```
def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts={}, mimetype="application/json", *args, **kwargs):
        content = simplejson.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

Since `simplejson` is going to be deprecated, can i use this

```
content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
```

or do I need to do more?

Comment: Did you test it? What was the outcome?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python

Comment: Is simplejson going to be deprecated?

Comment: @gecco actually have used that acrross the whole site and i have only tested few pages and its working fine, but i anot 100% sure that is ok across all parts

Comment: @parmod https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/712799/250168), `json` is `simplejson`. However, according to this [release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used), there might be some [incompatibilities](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18023#comment:10) depending on which version of `simplejson` you are currently using. Either way, you will want to replace `simplejson` with `json` at some point. Just make sure you test your code before pushing it out to production.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as that. Please read the bug report linked to in the Django documentation in the link in the question comments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer to reflect possible incompatibilities.

Answer (score 5):

Use python's json instead:

[Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used)

```
import json
```