# python google json api

Tags: python, api, simplejson

So i curentlly run this script that i found from http://www.dcortesi.com/blog/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/

```
import urllib
import simplejson
query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'the.hobbit.2012.imdb'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' \
 % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']
for i in results:
 if "imdb" in i['url']:
  print i['url']
  break
```

What i want is simply to get the first result from google containing imdb. (i need the movie id number)

My problem is, after like 4-6 searches i keep getting 
for about 15 seconds, then i can do 1 search again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g", line 9, in <module>
    results = json['responseData']['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

From what i have read google only allows a certin ammount of searches a day etc. But they should allow more then 10 searches a minute?

What else could be the problem here?
Or are there any other better way to search google? I only need the "highest" result that links to imdb.

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable `json`, you may get [confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python) if you try and load the actual module.

Comment: Why don't you just sign up for Google's search API? It's free.

Comment: Could you use [`imdbpy`](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) instead?

Comment: I actully put the movie id into imdbpy later in the script. But imdbpy search_movie seems very unreliable

Comment: @tsjk There's a known issue in imdbpy 4.9 with `search_movie` but is fixed in the [Mercurial repository](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google's Web Search API is deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html) (and rate limit enforcement is being tightened), so you have a couple options (in order of my preference):

1. Scrap the Google search altogether and use [imdbpy](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/overview).
2. Use [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started?hl=en) to avoid rate limit.

### IMDbPY Example

```
>>> import imdb    
>>> ia = imdb.IMDb()    
>>> movies = ia.search_movie(title='The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey')    
>>> movies[0].movieID    
'0903624'
```

Comment: Yes i think iam going with the Google Custom Search API, however haveing some trouble figuering out how to get the information that i need from that so we will see how it goes.