# Cannot import JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, macos, python-import

I am trying to make a following call:

```
from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
```

But I am getting this error:

```
from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
ImportError: cannot import name JSONDecodeError
```

The following information may help:

- This code runs fine in ubuntu but i get this error in **mac**.
- I had multiple versions of python and I just erased python 2.6 (as i am using **python 2.7**)
- and used `easy_install_27` to install this particular library.

Comment: Why do you want to import JSONDecodeError? Are you trying to import JSONDecoder instead?

Comment: Why not simply `import simplejson` and explicitly refer to whatever you need within that namespace?

Comment: Or import it from where it's defined, `from simplejson.scanner import JSONDecodeError`

Comment: for python 3, just `from json import JSONDecodeError`

Answer (score 34):

You already have the answer on how to get JSONDecodeError, but I feel that the correct advice should be that you shouldn't try to import it.

The reason is that JSONDecodeError appears only in `simplejson`, and there's not really a reason to use that unless your Python version is severely outdated. The built-in `json` is just as fast in recent versions, and has no unicode bug. Info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131316/723090

The solution: `json` raises a ValueError instead of JSONDecodeError, but JSONDecodeError (raised by `simplejson`) is a subclass of ValueError. So you could simply except a ValueError and it'll work for `json` and `simplejson`!

Answer (score 30):

Just to make more clear the comment of @tim, in python3 you can just write

```
from json import JSONDecodeError
```

No need for simplejson package

Comment: It's need for Python 3.4, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your installation:

```
$ pip install -U simplejson
$ python
>>> from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
```

Answer (score 1):

It works on my computer:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
>>>
```

Have you confirmed that you are running the installation of python in which the simplejson library is installed?  Check `sys.path` and verify that all of the expected locations are in the search path.  Does `import simplejson` work?  If so, verify from what file the module was loaded (`import simplejson; print simplejson.__file__`).  If that is as expected, then verify the contents of the module and see if the class JSONDecodeError exists in it.