# How to process a downloaded json string?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a json string and I am trying to print each section (id, name, link, etc) by using labels on tkinter GUI window.

Data:

```
{"id":"123456789","name":"John Smith","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/john.smith","username":"john.smith","gender":"male","locale":"en_GB"}
```

Code:

```
URL = https://graph.facebook.com/ + user
info = urlopen(info).read()
json_format = infor.decode("utf-8")
```

My problem is how do I assign each section of the json data to a variable do it can be printed out on a tkinter label?

thanks in advance

EDIT

Tried this code:

```
jsonData = json.loads(json_format)
u_name = jsoninfo['username']
```

and got the following error message

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: try doing this: u_name = jsonData['username']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) standard module:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = '{"id":"123456789","name":"John Smith","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/john.smith","username":"john.smith","gender":"male","locale":"en_GB"}'
>>> d = json.loads(data)
```

This gives you your data as a regular dictionary to use:

```
>>> d
{u'username': u'john.smith', u'first_name': u'John', u'last_name': u'Smith', u'name': u'John Smith', u'locale': u'en_GB', u'gender': u'male', u'link': u'http://www.facebook.com/john.smith', u'id': u'123456789'}
>>> d['username']
u'john.smith'
```

Comment: when I try that i get an error message, please check the edited question

Comment: There's an error in your sample: you used `jsoninfo` (which is apparently a string) insteach of `jsonData` (which is a dictionary).

Comment: What can I do if sometimes one of the json sections isn't present. How would I skip trying to load it without getting an error?

Comment: @user2148781 use json_data.get('key') instead of json_data['key']

Answer (score 1):

```py
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError: 
    import json

json_data = json.dumps(info)
# info here is json string or your variable json_format
```

Comment: whats the difference between simplejson and json?

Comment: Both work well, you can use any.
For more info check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `json` library - it is included in the standard library, and load the json. This will convert the json string to a Python dictionary which you can use.

```
import json

py_dict= json.loads(json_string)
# work away
```