# import json fails between GAE dev 1.7.0 and 1.7.7

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

Just updated GAE Python dev environment from 1.7.0 to 1.7.7, and hit an error:

```
ImportError: No module named json
```

So I created a minimum test case, here's the app.yap:

```
application: myapp

version: 1
api_version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true  

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"

handlers:
- url: /test.*
  script: test.app
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: routes.app
  login: required
```

and the test.py:

```
import webapp2
import json

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("test.py")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/test', MainHandler)],
    debug=True)
```

Switching dev environments is perfectly consistent - the error is thrown on 1.7.7 but not 1.7.0 (running dev environment from terminal on Linux). I've not tried uploading this to a production environment. It occurred while attempting to upgrade from Python 2.5 to 2.7, so may be due to my unfamiliarity with 2.7.

Comment: are you running the python 2.7 interpreter and runtime?  sounds like your python install might be missing the json library.

Comment: Yep, python -V gives Python 2.7.3. Also, it runs fine when I downgrade the dev environment to 1.7.0 from the latest (1.7.7).

Comment: Can you `import json` in the python interpreter?

Comment: Yes. Have found my noobie error, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a noobie mistake. As mentioned, I was upgrading from 2.5 to 2.7, during which I moved from importing simplejson to json.

During 2.5 development, I had created a file called json.py, which of course caused a conflict when upgrading to 2.7 and trying to import json, so I renamed that file. Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that, but if I had done so, I would have realized... the json.pyc was still hanging around!

Removing the json.pyc file fixed it. However, it doesn't explain why the presence of json.pyc affected 1.7.7 but not 1.7.0 - switching between the two was perfectly repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for simplejson, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/json-and-simplejson-module-differences-in-python), except I think in GAE you get simplejson from django.utils:

```
try: from django.utils import simplejson as json
except ImportError: import json
```

But the [Python 2.7 runtime should allow](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27#JSON_Version) for `import json`. If the above worked, you were probably running on 2.5.

Comment: Yep, had tried that (without try block), and get ImportError: No module named django.utils

Comment: Yes, the dev environment, dev_appserver, under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) with Python 2.7.

Comment: You can't get a  ImportError: No module named django.utils if you are import json with  

`import json` and you are running python2.7 and an out of the box 1.7.7 SDK.