# python list with true and false not True and False

Tags: python

-----------------------  UPDATED  ----------------------

Since there was so much confusion, I decided to give a more detailed explanation. Take a look at the code below, and focus on

```
day = {"days": buildString2(day_array[i])}
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv, sys, requests, json, os, itertools, ast

def buildString(item):
    item_array = item.split(",")
    mod = []
    for i in range(len(item_array)):
        mod.append("%s" % item_array[i].strip())
    return mod

def buildString2(item):
    item_array = item.split(",")
    mod = "["
    for i in range(len(item_array)):
        if i == len(item_array) - 1:
            mod = mod + '%s' % item_array[i].strip()
        else:
            mod = mod + '%s, ' % item_array[i].strip()
    mod = mod + "]"
    return mod

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def main():
        filename = 'file.csv'
        dict = {"id":'c8d5185667f'}

        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            try:
                count = 0
                for row in reader:
                    count = count + 1
                    if count != 1:

                        dict["name"] = row[10]

                        dict["space_usages"] = buildString(row[19])

                        availablle_array = []
                        available_booking_hours = row[15]
                        days = row[18]
                        availability_array = available_booking_hours.split("*")
                        day_array = days.split("*")
                        for i in range(len(day_array)):
                            startEndTime = availability_array[i].split("-")
                            day = {"days": buildString2(day_array[i])}
                            times = {"start_time":startEndTime[0], "end_time":startEndTime[1]}
                            day["times"] = times
                            availablle_array.append(day)

                        dict["available_days"] = availablle_array

                        print(dict)
                        url = 'http://50.97.247.68:9000/api/v1/spaces'
                        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(dict))
```

When I print dict, I get the following

```
{'id': 'c8d5185667f', 'available_days': [{'days': '[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]', 'times': {'start_time': '12:00', 'end_time': '10:00'}}], 'space_usages': ['Fitness', 'Events', 'Classes', 'Performance']}
```

but my boss wants this

```
{'id': 'c8d5185667f', 'available_days': [{'days': [true, true, true, true, true, true, true], 'times': {'start_time': '12:00', 'end_time': '10:00'}}], 'space_usages': ['Fitness', 'Events', 'Classes', 'Performance']}
```

this doesn't work either

```
{'id': 'c8d5185667f', 'available_days': [{'days': ['true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true'], 'times': {'start_time': '12:00', 'end_time': '10:00'}}], 'space_usages': ['Fitness', 'Events', 'Classes', 'Performance']}
```

Does this make more sense? Is it possible to get

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

as a value? I tried doing this

```
day = {"days": ast.literal_eval(buildString2(day_array[i]))}
```

but it crashes. I'm out of ideas. I've tried googling a variety of things, and I can't seem to find anything. Your help is greatly appreciated. I honestly don't believe this is possible, but that's what I've been told to do.

NOTE: They have to be lowercase. This doesn't work

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the input format and what is the expected output?

Comment: Seems that you want some JSON.

Comment: If the REST API takes JSON posts, just use actual boolean values in Python and use `json.dumps()` to encode that to JSON.

Comment: How does the REST API work, i.e. is it built using HTTP? If so, how does your API expect to receive the parameter which is a list of booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *possible* to get what your boss wants, just not using the built-in True and False:

```
class MyBool(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = bool(value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value).lower()
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value

print({'a' : [MyBool(True), MyBool(True), MyBool(False)]})
```

Result:

```
{'a': [true, true, false]}
```

You don't actually need `__bool__`, but (in Python 3) it allows the objects to be used in logical conditions.

So as requested, it's not a valid Python literal since it uses `true` instead of `True`,  and it's not valid JSON since it uses single-quoted key strings instead of double-quoted. Presumably it's parsed by something that doesn't accept `True` and also doesn't accept double-quoted strings? I don't suppose there's any chance of just fixing the original API to accept JSON?

Comment: Haha, this produces what my boss wanted, but like you mentioned true is not valid JSON. So it crashes when I try json.dumps(dict) with "TypeError: true is not JSON serializable". Thanks for the help. I had a feeling this wasn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is JSON, so you should just convert your week into JSON format

```
In [1]: import simplejson as json
In [2]: week = [True, False, True, True]
In [3]: json.dumps(week)
Out[3]: '[true, false, true, true]'
```

To convert back, just load and parse it:

```
In [8]: print json.loads('[true, false, false, true]')
[True, False, False, True]
```

Comment: `simplejson` of `json`?

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the REST API uses JSON, but it seems that the OP is already aware of the possibility to encode a list of booleans as a string like `[true, false, true, false]`. I think his confusion stems from elsewhere.

Comment: import simplejson as json

Comment: Why `simplejson` instead of the built-in module `json`?

Comment: @MaximeLorant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-simplejson-python-modules aims to settle the issue. And read past the first answer, since the "right" answer changes some time between 2009 and 2013 ;-)

Comment: but what if I want out[3]:[true, false, true, true]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to convert your boolean list to a string and reciprocally:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([True, False, True, True, False])
'[true, false, true, true, false]'
>>> json.loads('[true, false, true, true, false]')
[True, False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: I updated my question. Instead of '[true, false, true, true, false]' can the output be [true, false, true, true, false]?

Answer (score 0):

Your value is

```
week = '[true, false, true, false, true, false, true]'
```

Which is JSON representation. Second value is

```
week = ['true', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'true']
```

Which is List with "true" and "false" strings.

```
week = [True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Which is pure python code.

You have to decide which value you have and which way you have to select to convert it in which form.

For first value you can use `json.loads`.

For second value you have to check manually string for "true" and "false"

Third is python only so no need to change it in python again :).