# Sending form data from Angular to Django

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to post some data from AngualrJS to a Django backend.

My code looks like this:

**angular**

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'path/to/django/',
    data: $scope.formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});
```

**django view**

```
import json

class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        # Do stuff
```

However, the `json` module complains:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Why is the data not sent as JSON and how should I best convert the payload to a Python object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `Content-type` to `application/json`

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

It's also worth noting that the default angular `$http POST` behavior is to send the data as JSON. So another strategy might be to remove `headers` from your `$http` call altogether.

Also, you may want to use `simplejson` rather than `json`

The following explanation was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-simplejson-python-modules):

`json` is `simplejson`, added to the python stdlib. But since `json` was added in 2.6, `simplejson` has the advantage of working on more Python versions (2.4+).

`simplejson` is also updated more frequently than Python, so if you need (or want) the latest version, it's best to use `simplejson` if possible.

Comment: `type(request.body)` is still `<class 'bytes'>`

Comment: just fixed a typo (had `=` instead of `:`).  how about now?

Comment: additionaly, you might try using/importing `simplejson` rather than `json` in your django view

Comment: Yeah, switched out for `simplejson` and now it works ;)

Comment: If you want to add that to your answer, I'll accept it ;)

Comment: you bet. it's up there now.  :)