# creating JSON format output

Tags: java, python, json, perl, scripting

I am trying to write a program which can create an output in JSON format, how would be best way of doing this? and programming languages?

This is an example output of JSON (expected output) which I need to input in the Name, Gender, Qualification and other attributes in a user friendly way during the execution of script. And in which outputs in following JSON format. Sorry, I am new in programming, but so much interested to learn Perl (or) Python (or) Java.  What could be the best here?

Any suggestions?

P.S Sorry I am quite new to JSON as well, please apologize me for this basic one.

```
[
    {
        "Name":"Steven Mark",
        "gender":"male",
        "Qualification": {
            "college":"Bachelor in Science",
            "tech":"certified pro"
        },
        "contributions": [
            {
                "name":"biography",
                "type":"book",
            },
       ]
    },
    {
        "Name":"Andrea Mark",
        "Gender":"female",
        "Qualifications": {
            "college":"Bachelor in physics",
        },
        "contributions": [
            {
                "name":"my insights",
                "type":"movie",
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to decide at least which language you're going to use first; without that decision (which is yours to make), this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Learn to indent properly to find mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Virtually every language has a JSON library, including Perl.

```
use JSON;

my $data = [
    {
        "Name" => "Steven Mark",
        "gender" => "male",
        "Qualification" => {
            "college" => "Bachelor in Science",
            "tech" => "certified pro"
        },
        "contributions" => [
            {
                "name" => "biography",
                "type" => "book",
            },
       ]
    },
    {
        "Name" => "Andrea Mark",
        "Gender" => "female",
        "Qualifications" => {
            "college" => "Bachelor in physics",
        },
        "contributions" => [
            {
                "name" => "my insights",
                "type" => "movie",
            },
        ]
    }
];

print(encode_json($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to use ANY programming language, i can suggest python. With its json lib you can do following (lines with # is comments):

```
# import lib
import json
# fill data into variable (this is list with dict objects inside):
data = [{"name":"john"},{"name": "bill"}]
# dump json
json.dumps(data)
```

Which will output your data as json. 
You can start writing python using something from https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Python, you can try to use `simplejson` or `json` module to create a json object.

For example,

```
try:
    import simplejson
except:
    import json

data = dict(a=1,b=2)
with open("results.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=3, encoding="utf-8")
```

> For dumping, json is faster than simplejson (but not by an order of magnitude). For loading, simplejson is faster (but not by an order of magnitude).

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-simplejson-python-modules) for more detailed comparison between `simplejson` and `json`.