# Python3: unable to import JSONDecodeError from json.decoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplejson

I setup virtualenv using python 3.4.3 and tried to import JSONDecodeError from json.decoder

```
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError (I think its valid in python3 ? But why not working for me ?)
```

But it is not working. Only below is working:

```
from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
```

How I did ?

```
virtualenv venv --no-site-packages -p python3 
pip install ipython
ipython
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError'
```

[image]

Comment: Is your file named `json.py`? Please provide full traceback.

Comment: from json import JSONDecodeError

Comment: Strange, this works fine for me. Can you see what happens if you try `from json import decoder; print(decoder.JSONDecodeError)` ?

Comment: In [8]: print(decoder.JSONDecodeError)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bb2acb16c5bc> in <module>()
----> 1 print(decoder.JSONDecodeError)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecodeError'

Comment: Attached screenshot also

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [3.4.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html), plain `ValueError` is raised when JSON decoding fails.

`JSONDecodeError` class is available starting from [3.5.x](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError).

Comment: Indeed. And since `JSONDecodeError` inherits from `ValueError` it is best to catch the latter if you care about portability.

Answer (score 2):

According to Docs from [module json (Python version >= 3.5.0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), Python which version < 3.5.0 does not support import statement like what you just did, but if you use Python(version>=3.5.0), your import statement is definitely correct.

Answer (score 0):

json is the version of simplejson that has been integrated into Python. They have since been developed separately and are not the same anymore. So they cannot necessarily be used interchangably.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-simplejson-python-modules) for more details about the differences.

Comment: Can you clarify whether 
'from json import JSONDecodeError' is right or wrong in python3 ?

Comment: As mentioned in other answers it depends on the minor version. If your questioned isn't "Why does this work with simplejson but not with json?" then I misunderstood.