# Svn log output json format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, svn

I am a beginner with subversions. Is it possible to get svn log ouput in json format using linux commands. In fact, I want to see the history of the commits of one file.

I tried following command:

```
svn log file:///var/svn/repository/test.txt
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r40166 | user1 | 2013-11-22 12:20:51 +0530 (Fri, 22 Nov 2013) | 1 line

Removed whitespace
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r40107 | user1 | 2013-11-21 14:24:16 +0530 (Thu, 21 Nov 2013) | 1 line

Commited text file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to get output in json format? If no, Is there any way to parse above output to show as table using jquery?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't noticed SVN has an `--xml` output option.  I'd suggest using that and then using some code to convert XML to JSON.  You should be able to find lots of advice how to do that online.  For instance here's a [Stack Overflow question about doing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471946/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Ones suggestion would be write svn-hooks for the log command. An introduction to svn hooks for Windows could be found here - http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/. Additionally for Linux (for pre-commit) is here but you can extend the concept for svn log command - http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php.
In similar way you can write a shell script to transform the text file output to jSON format.

Comment: Hooks really are not going to be helpful to him.  They're mostly there to allow the server side to make decisions about incoming changes (e.g. pre-commit, pre-revprop-change) and to trigger actions after commits (e.g. post-commit, post-revprop-change).  Writing a hook script that transforms log data into JSON isn't going to be any easier than doing it from a client.