# How to convert xml tags into dictionary using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add elements in a dictionary keeping key,value pair using python. My input is xml and expected output should be dictionary.

Input:-

```
<math>
    <elements>
        <function>
           <val>ADD</val>
        </function>
        <operator>
           <val>+</val>
        </operator>
        <function>
           <val>SUB</val>
        </function>
        <operator>
           <val>-</val>
        </operator>
    </elements>
</math>
```

I tried parsing and converting it into dictionary but no help. I am using lxml and don't want to use xmltodict.

```
code till now:- 

from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import _ElementTree, _Element, XMLParser
tree = etree.parsexml('math.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
mathdict = {}

for item in root.findall('./math/elements/function/'):
    for d in root.findall('./math/elements/operator/'):
        mathdict[item.text] = d.text
```

It should return dictionary like below:-
[ADD:+,SUB:-]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471946/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-python

Comment: @amrit i already checked the above link but it's not solving what i am looking for i want a recursive function for two childs and between them one is value and another is key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order of the XML is always going to be "correct", you can use [`.iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


string = '''<math>
                <elements>
                    <function>
                       <val>ADD</val>
                    </function>
                    <operator>
                       <val>+</val>
                    </operator>
                    <function>
                       <val>SUB</val>
                    </function>
                    <operator>
                           <val>-</val>
                    </operator>
                </elements>
            </math>'''

root = ET.fromstring(string)

output = {}

functions, operators = root.iter('function'), root.iter('operator')

for function, operator in zip(functions, operators):
    output[function.find('val').text] = operator.find('val').text

print(output)
# {'ADD': '+', 'SUB': '-'}
```

The dictionary creation and loop can be condensed to a dict comprehension:

```
output = {function.find('val').text: operator.find('val').text
          for function, operator in zip(functions, operators)}
```

Comment: It is a good answer but what if this xml has another tag with same tags, like <math1>....</math1> ?

Comment: @Pyjava Then this answer can be easily modified. I answered using the XML in the example

Comment: Got it Thanks . I figured out a way to do that.