# API + pandas+excel = datas

Tags: python

I am new to python. Due to I need your help.

I have excel file having some numbers and API of a website where I can download numbers and it returns some info about each number. 
I 've searched and found that library as requests can do.

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel('numbers.xlsx')
for number in df['num']:
    r = requests.get('https://example.com/datas=%s'%number')
    print (r.text)
```

However, I don't know how to get data from API response

Output from API response is like that:

```
age: 0
lat: 70.0000
lon: 70.0000
url: example.com
```

I wanna only output of age. However, I guess it's not dictionary and not JSON, because I print:

1) `print (r['age'])` - TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Then I did this:

2)

```
res = r.json()
print(res["age"])
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

How can I extract only age value?

Also how is possible to increase speed of the script, because going through 20.000 numbers takes few hours.((

Comment: can i know type of api response

Comment: try printing r and see what object you are getting in return

Comment: have you tried casting the json as a pandas dataframe: ``df = pd.read_json(r.json())``  ? (see: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content )

Comment: response is not in JSON format. You can't get it using `r.json()`. You can manually get first line - `data = r.text.splitlines()[0]` - and skip `"age: "` (4 chars) - `data = data[4:]` or `data = data.replace("age: ", "")`. And then you can convert it to `int()`

Comment: @venkatadileep - XML

Comment: @furas  - result: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: BTW: it is always good to show real URL. Maybe it has some documentation and maybe it need extra argument to return it as JSON.

Comment: @furas  - I can not cuz its private website of company:) Sorry

Comment: @LanaBash- try these convert xml to json(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471946/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-python) and run with query it might work .

Answer (score 0):

1. you might take eventlet into your coding to solve the low speed problem.
2. as to the error that you are dealing with while use syntax like res['age'], you may try:

```
import json

res = json.loads(res)
res['age']
```

Comment: Sorry, but here is : the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

Answer (score 0):

If you get normal text instead JSON data then you can use string functions for get it.

```
text = '''age: 0
lat: 70.0000
lon: 70.0000
url: example.com'''

all_lines = text.splitlines()
line = all_lines[0]  # get first line
age = line[5:]  # skip "age: "
#age = int(age) 
print(age)
```

Comment: PL: Proszę bardzo.