# pyparsing results as a JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pyparsing

After one day of looking through Internet I ask this question here:

Is there any way to get **pyparsing** results, f.e.

```
result = longSentence.parseString(text.lower())
```

in a **JSON** format?

**Update 11:46 27 May 2013:**
Ok. So I try to make a parser for easy English.
The results for a sentence *"Go 5 metres and what do you see?"* now are printed as lists:

```
[[[['go'], [['5', 'metres']]]], 'and', ['what do you see?']]
```

`['what do you see?']` is marked by `SetResultsName('Question')`
Others are marked similar.

It would be great if it will print that data in this form:

```
{
    "Sentence1":
    {
        "Order":
        {
            "Predicate": 'go',
            "Subject": ['5', 'metres']
        }
    },
    "Sentence2":
    {
        "Question": 'what do you see?'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After another try of going through documentation I found a very nice way to return this data in a **XML** form:

```
result = longSentence.parseString(text.lower()).asXML()
```

If I add [this question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python) - it's done. So it's not so easy, but also not so hard to get results in **JSON** form. I hope anyone in need will find that.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to be more explicit, but the general approach would to be to take the parse result and use the `json` module (whether you want this as a nested dictionary/list, flattened list/etc... is up to you)

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps(result.asList())
```

Comment: This will represent everything as lists and drop all the `.setResultName`'s