# Quickest way to convert XML to python object

Tags: python, xml

Is there any way to convert XML to python model, instead of write parsing manually?

Comment: Python model???

Comment: I try xml.etree.ElementTree and lxml but my file is about 7000 lines alot of element So I try to find automated model generate.

Comment: I mean python object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting XML to JSON using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python)

Answer (score 3):

Try [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

> `xmltodict` is a Python module that makes working with XML feel like you are working with [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), as in this ["spec"](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html):

```
>>> print(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse("""
...  <mydocument has="an attribute">
...    <and>
...      <many>elements</many>
...      <many>more elements</many>
...    </and>
...    <plus a="complex">
...      element as well
...    </plus>
...  </mydocument>
...  """), indent=4))
{
    "mydocument": {
        "@has": "an attribute", 
        "and": {
            "many": [
                "elements", 
                "more elements"
            ]
        }, 
        "plus": {
            "@a": "complex", 
            "#text": "element as well"
        }
    }
}
```