# How can i obtain a JSON response from microsoft azure cognitive services text translation API

Tags: azure, text, translation, azure-cognitive-services

I want data returned in JSON format instead of XML in the following code,  where  `headers` is the key to the API. `requests.get(translateUrl,headers=headers)` gives XML.

## Call to Microsoft Translator Service

```
headers = {"Authorization ": finalToken}
translateUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text={}&to={}".format(textToTranslate, toLangCode)

translationData = requests.get(translateUrl, headers = headers)

# parse xml return values
translation = ElementTree.fromstring(translationData.text.encode('utf-8'))

# display translation
print (translation.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing [feature request](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator/suggestions/18469786-json) for this.

For now you will have to convert it on the client side.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python) is where you might additional info.