# attributes not appearing in xml2dict parse output even with xml_attribs = True

Tags: python, xml, attributes, xmltodict

I am having a problem with python xmltodict.  Following the near-consensus recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201405/811299), I tried xmltodict and liked it very much until I had to access attributes at the top level of my handler. I'm probably doing something wrong but it's not clear to me what. I have an xml document looking something like this

```
<api>
<cons id="79550" modified_dt="1526652449">
<firstname>Mackenzie</firstname>
...
</cons>
<cons id="79551" modified_dt="1526652549">
<firstname>Joe</firstname>
...
</cons>
<api>
```

I parse it with this:

```
xmltodict.parse(apiResult.body, item_depth=2, item_callback=handler, xml_attribs=True)
```

where `apiResult.body` contains the xml shown above.  But, in spite of the  `xml_attribs=True`,  I see no `@id` or `@modified_dt` in the output after parsing in the handler, although all the **elements** in the original do appear.

The handler is coded as follows:

```
def handler(_, cons):
    print (cons)
    mc = MatchChecker(cons)
    mc.check()
    return True
```

What might I be doing wrong?

I've also tried xmljson and instantly don't like it as well as xmltodict, if only I had the way around this issue.  Does anyone have a solution to this problem or a package that would handle this better?

Answer (score 1):

`xmltodict` works just fine, but you are parsing the argument `item_depth=2` which means your handler will only see the elements inside the `<cons>` elements rather than the `<cons>` element itself.

```
xml = """
<api>
<cons id="79550" modified_dt="1526652449">
<firstname>Mackenzie</firstname>
</cons>
</api>
"""

def handler(_,arg):
    for i in arg.items():
        print(i)
    return True

xmltodict.parse(xml, item_depth=2, item_callback=handler, xml_attribs=True)
```

Prints `('firstname', 'Mackenzie')` as expected.

Whereas:

```
xmltodict.parse(xml, item_depth=1, item_callback=handler, xml_attribs=True)
```

Prints `('cons', OrderedDict([('@id', '79550'), ('@modified_dt', '1526652449'), ('firstname', 'Mackenzie')]))`, again as expected.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense, I guess, but with the depth of 2, I was able to access the firstname field as d["firstname"], as I expected to, but with a depth of 1,  will I have to access it as d["cons"]["firstname"]?

Comment: @SteveCohen yes, that's right but it then allows to access the `id` for example as `d["cons"]["@id"]`.

Comment: No, this still doesn't make sense to me.  depth 1 returns an ARRAY of depth 2 elements corresponding to the cons element in the xml.  The id is logically associated with the depth 2 element.  When I work at depth 1 even if I use the d["cons']['firstname'] syntax, I get the "list indices must be integers, not str" error.  I suppose I could iterate through the list in the handler, but why should I have to? Depth 2 is what I want and I still don't understand why the attributes don't show up.

Comment: I think this is a bug in xmltodict.  I think from a look at its code, all depth levels below the specified depth automatically get the xml_attribs set true (whether asked for or not), but at the requested depth, xml_attribs is False.  That is why using a depth level of 1 in my case gets the attributes.  In my case the attributes belong at depth level 2.