# using python to convert XML to Json and trigger a post API request

Tags: python, json, xml, post

im lookning for a solution to convert XML to Json and use the Json as the payload for post request.

I'm aiming for the following logic:

1. search for all root.listing.scedules.s and parse @s @d @p @c.
2. in root.listing.programs parse @t [p.id = @p (from scedules)] ->"Prime Discussion"

3, in root.listing.channels parse @c [c.id = @c (from scedules)] -> "mychannel"

4. once I have all the info parsed, I want to build a JSON containing all the params and send it using post request

I also look for a solution which will trigger multiple post APIs as the number of root.listing.scedules.s elements

```
{
"time":"{@s}",
"durartion":"{@d}",
"programID":"{@p}",
"title":"{@t}",
"channelName":"{@c}",
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<listings>
<schedules>
<s s="2019-09-26T00:00:00" d="1800" p="1569735" c="100007">
<f id="3" />
</s>
</schedules>
<programs>
<p id="1569735" t="Prime Discussion" d="Discussion on Current Affairs." rd="Discussion on Current Affairs." l="en">
<f id="2" />
<f id="21" />
<k id="6" v="20160614" />
<k id="1" v="2450548" />
<k id="18" v="12983658" />
<k id="21" v="12983658" />
<k id="10" v="Program" />
<k id="19" v="SH024505480000" />
<k id="20" v="http://tmsimg.com/assets/p12983658_b_h5_aa.jpg" />
<c id="607" />
<r o="1" r="1" n="100" />
<r o="2" r="1" n="1000" />
<r o="3" r="1" n="10000" />
</p>
</programs>
</listings>
<channels>
<c id="100007" c="mychannel" l="Prime Asia TV SD" d="Prime Asia TV SD" t="Digital" iso639="hi" />
<c id="10035" c="AETV" l="A&amp;amp;E Canada" d="A&amp;amp;E Canada" t="Digital" u="WWW.AETV.COM" iso639="en" />
</channels>
</root>
```

currently, i use this code to parse the scedules.s elements (part 1) and need some help  with parts 2,3,4

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('ChannelsProgramsTest.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for sched in root[0][0].findall('s'):
    new = sched.get('s'),sched.get('p'),sched.get('d'),sched.get('c')
    print(new)
```

Comment: What did you try do far?

Comment: i succeed to parse the attributes using xml.etree.ElementTree library. as this is new to me i am looking for some help in order to build the needed logic

Comment: Share your current code please

Comment: `code`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('ChannelsProgramsTest.xml')

root = tree.getroot()



for sched in root[0][0].findall('s'):
    new = sched.get('s'),sched.get('p'),sched.get('d'),sched.get('c')
    print(new)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Explain that you want to do A,B,C.. and the code does only A. Ask how to do B,C as well.

Comment: added, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Below (I think it is the core solution you were looking for)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <listings>
      <schedules>
         <s s="2019-09-26T00:00:00" d="1800" p="1569735" c="100007">
            <f id="3" />
         </s>
      </schedules>
      <programs>
         <p id="1569735" t="Prime Discussion" d="Discussion on Current Affairs." rd="Discussion on Current Affairs." l="en">
            <f id="2" />
            <f id="21" />
            <k id="6" v="20160614" />
            <k id="1" v="2450548" />
            <k id="18" v="12983658" />
            <k id="21" v="12983658" />
            <k id="10" v="Program" />
            <k id="19" v="SH024505480000" />
            <k id="20" v="http://tmsimg.com/assets/p12983658_b_h5_aa.jpg" />
            <c id="607" />
            <r o="1" r="1" n="100" />
            <r o="2" r="1" n="1000" />
            <r o="3" r="1" n="10000" />
         </p>
      </programs>
   </listings>
   <channels>
      <c id="100007" c="mychannel" l="Prime Asia TV SD" d="Prime Asia TV SD" t="Digital" iso639="hi" />
      <c id="10035" c="AETV" l="A&amp;amp;E Canada" d="A&amp;amp;E Canada" t="Digital" u="WWW.AETV.COM" iso639="en" />
   </channels>
</root>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
listings = tree.findall('.//listings')
for entry in listings:
    # This is the first requirement: find s,d,p,c under 's' element
    s = entry.find('./schedules/s')
    print(s.attrib)
    # now that we have s,d,p,c we can move on and look for the program with a specific id
    program = entry.find("./programs/p[@id='{}']".format(s.attrib['p']))
    print(program.attrib['t'])
    # find the channel
    channel = tree.find(".//channels/c[@id='{}']".format(s.attrib['c']))
    print(channel.attrib['c'])
```

output

```
{'s': '2019-09-26T00:00:00', 'd': '1800', 'p': '1569735', 'c': '100007'}
Prime Discussion
mychannel
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still somewhat new to Stackoverflow in usage but not years. I think this is a somewhat duplicate question but I do not know how to tag this as duplicate yet.

---

A very good explanation of XML to JSON via Python is in the following post by the author of the library suggested.

---

[Converting XML to JSON using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python)

---

The data source may have unknown characters in it that you will need to code for if you don't use a library

---

ie, newlines, unicode characters, other 'stray' characters. Often libraries will have done this for you already and you don't have to re-invent the wheel.