# How to get full name of an element in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

Having the following xml,

```
<markets xmlns:cap="URI">
    <us>
        <summary>
            <index>NASDAQ</index>
            <last>34,000</last>
            <cap:change>-2.4</cap:change>
        </summary>
    </us>
</markets>
```

Let's assume I've an Element that points to `NASDAQ`,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
markets = ET.parse('markets.xml')
// some processing here
index = # pointing to `NASDAQ` element here
```

how can I get the element full path as `markets.us.summary.index`?

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, there are [some ideas here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python). If you don't mind using lxml, [objectify does this](https://lxml.de/3.1/objectify.html).

Comment: "full path as `markets.us.summary.index`" - you can get the full XPATH of the `<index>` node (which will be something like `/markets/us/summary/index `) using lxml, if that's what your are really looking for.