# How to make a nested dict (json) from a schema database xml?

Tags: python, json, xml

Here is my input `file.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="so_project" id="Project-9999">
    <schema name="database1">
        <table name="table1">
            <column name="foo" type="int"/>
            <column name="bar" type="string"/>
            <column name="details_resolution" type="array[object]">
                <column name="timestamp" type="timestamp"/>
                <column name="user_id" type="string"/>
                <column name="user_name" type="string"/>
            </column>
            <column name="details_closure" type="array[object]">
                <column name="timestamp" type="timestamp"/>
                <column name="auto_closure" type="bool"/>
            </column>
        </table>
    </schema>
    <schema name="database2">
        <table name="table1">
            <column name="foo" type="int"/>
            <column name="bar" type="string"/>
            <column name="details" type="array[object]">
                <column name="timestamp" type="timestamp"/>
                <column name="value" type="float"/>
            </column>
        </table>
    </schema>
</project>
```

.. and I'm trying to make this classical nested dict :

```py
{
    "database1": {
        "table1": {
            "foo": "int",
            "bar": "string",
            "details_resolution": {
                "timestamp": "timestamp",
                "user_id": "string",
                "user_name": "string"
            },
            "details_closure": {
                "timestamp": "timestamp",
                "auto_closure": "bool"
            }
        }
    },
    "database2": {
        "table1": {
            "foo": "int",
            "bar": "string",
            "details": {
                "timestamp": "timestamp",
                "value": "float"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*PS : Each database can eventually have more than one table.*

I tried some AI codes but none of them gave me the expected result..
I'm sorry guys to not being able to show my attempts !

SO, any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting XML to JSON using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191536/converting-xml-to-json-using-python)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. I wonder why my question get closed even though the linked duplicate did not solve my problem..

Comment: I'm afraid it's very common for experienced users on this site to close questions as duplicates, because as experts they can see that the two questions are essentially equivalent, when unfortunately beginners might not recognize that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse_column(column_elem):
    column_data = {}
    column_data['name'] = column_elem.get('name')
    column_data['type'] = column_elem.get('type')
    return column_data

def parse_table(table_elem):
    table_data = {}
    table_name = table_elem.get('name')
    for column_elem in table_elem.findall('column'):
        column_data = parse_column(column_elem)
        table_data[column_data['name']] = column_data['type']
    return {table_name: table_data}

def parse_schema(schema_elem):
    schema_data = {}
    schema_name = schema_elem.get('name')
    for table_elem in schema_elem.findall('table'):
        table_data = parse_table(table_elem)
        schema_data.update(table_data)
    return {schema_name: schema_data}

def parse_xml(xml_content):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)
    project_data = {}
    for schema_elem in root.findall('schema'):
        schema_data = parse_schema(schema_elem)
        project_data.update(schema_data)
    return project_data

# Read XML file
with open('file.xml', 'r') as f:
    xml_content = f.read()

# Parse XML and generate nested dictionary
nested_dict = parse_xml(xml_content)
print(nested_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("your_file.xml", "r") as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "xml")


def parse_columns(t):
    out = {}
    for c in t.find_all("column", recursive=False):
        if c.find("column"):
            out[c["name"]] = parse_columns(c)
        else:
            out[c["name"]] = c["type"]
    return out


def parse_schema(sch):
    out = {}
    for t in sch.select("table"):
        out[t["name"]] = parse_columns(t)
    return out


out = {}
for sch in soup.select("schema"):
    out[sch["name"]] = parse_schema(sch)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "database1": {
        "table1": {
            "foo": "int",
            "bar": "string",
            "details_resolution": {
                "timestamp": "timestamp",
                "user_id": "string",
                "user_name": "string",
            },
            "details_closure": {"timestamp": "timestamp", "auto_closure": "bool"},
        }
    },
    "database2": {
        "table1": {
            "foo": "int",
            "bar": "string",
            "details": {"timestamp": "timestamp", "value": "float"},
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: I love you, thank you so much! You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0:

```
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/schema"/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
     <xsl:map-entry key="string(@name)">
        <xsl:map>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:map>
     </xsl:map-entry>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:map-entry key="string(@name)" select="string(@type)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdvWh3 for the full stylesheet including boilerplate.

Explanation:

- The first template rule matches the document, creates the outermost map, and processes the `schema` element, skipping the `project` level.
- The second template rule matches elements that have one or more children; it creates a map entry for the container element with the @name attribute as the key, and generates another map as the content, by applying template rules to the children recursively.
- The third template rule matches elements with no children; it creates a map entry for the container element, with `@name` as the key and `@type` as the corresponding value.